# SQL CTE is not practical with a lot of calculated column

Tags: sql, sqlite, join, common-table-expression

SQLite can handle at most 64 tables in a join. It can be too few if you need a lot of calculated column and you are using CTE.

For sake of simplicity let us say you have table with an ID and Weight. You want to create view with a lot of calculated column based on weight using CTE. 
E.g.: calc1 = weight + 3, calc2 = calc1 * 2; calc3 = calc2 / 26 + 6, ...
There are join in the cte's as well as in the main select. The 64 table join limit can be reached easily. Of course the example is oversimplification.

I just see one workaround, not to use CTE but build each calculated column from scratch. But in this way there will be huge formulas. Is there a better way?

```
  WITH calc1Cte AS (
      SELECT
        [Id],
        [Weight] + 3
          AS [calc1]
      FROM [Transaction]
  ), calc2Cte AS (
      SELECT
        [Id],
        calc1 *2 
        AS calc2
      FROM [Transaction] AS A JOIN [calc1Cte] AS B
      where A.Id = B.Id
  ), calc3Cte AS (
    ...
  ) ...
SELECT
    [Id],
    [Weight],
    [calc1],
...
 FROM [Transaction] AS "TOut"
    JOIN calc1Cte ON TOut.Id = calc1Cte.Id
    JOIN calc2Cte ON TOut.Id = calc2Cte.Id
...
```

Comment: Why do you need to join? Just do `WITH calc1Cte AS (
      SELECT
        [Id],
        [Weight] + 3
          AS [calc1]
      FROM [Transaction]
  ), calc2Cte AS (
      SELECT
        [Id],
        calc1 *2 
        AS calc2
     FROM [calc1Cte]
  ), calc3Cte AS (
    ...
  ) ...`

Comment: Consider returning only unique data and doing the calculations as needed in the display level.  In your example, calc2 doesn't need to be returned as it's simply calc1*2 and your display level can handle that.

Comment: I shudder to think about a 64+ table join, but if you absolutely have to use more than 64 tables to find all your calculated values, consider splitting the work into chunks and using temp tables to store intermediate values.

Comment: Why do you need a join? And your query is incomprehensible without `A.` and `B.` on the columns.

Comment: Thanks @MartinSmith ! It works perfectly. My logic was that the CTE contains only the Id and the calculated column, so if I need some column from the original table I use join, if I need a column from a previous cte I use join again. If I select all columns from the original table in the first cte, then the second cte does not need the original table so no join is needed. Thanks again.